# Cannot retrieve auth token via API - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product

Tags: autodesk-forge

I recently activated trial version of APS in order to test one of APIs for my application. I got stuck though when trying to get the token by calling "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token". I am using Postman and I believe I inputted everything correctly. Even tried decoding ClientID and Secret from Base64 to check whetehr it is encoded correctly and it seems it is.

The error I am getting is:

"developerMessage": "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product",
"moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": "AUTH-001"

In app setting all APIs are allowed.

Am I missing something?